# Issue with AWS Cognito Authorizer attached with API Gateway

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I have created a REST API using aws api gateway and i have integrated a lambda function with it. I have also attached a Cognito Authorizer with it for authentication purpose. But I am facing one issue with the cognito authorizer. The access token which is issued on successful authentication of a user from the user pool in the cognito, does not get nullified even after the user is deleted from the user pool.
I am actually trying to implement a logout functionality in my application, and since I am using cognito authorizer, I want that his access token should get invalidated and he should not be able to access the APIs using that token. After logout when he comes back, a new token should be issued.
But I am not able to meet my purpose using AWS Cognito. Please help me out.

I have read the documentation of AWS Cognito and many blogs but no solution for invalidation of access token could be found.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.